# MVPVM - Enum use in Model and View Model

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, architecture, model, viewmodel

Say I have a Model object:

```
class MyModel
{
int status { get; set; }
...
}
```

and corresponding View Model:

```
class MyViewModel
{
Enums.Status status { get; set; }
...
}
```

The Model objects are read/written to an XML file, with the status as a numerical value.
In the View, the View Model statuses are translated to strings via a resource file lookup.

Currently, we need to translate the status from int int the Model to Enums.Status in the View Model.

In the interests of simplifying this and giving more meaning to the numerical values in the Model, is it acceptable if I use the same Enum for both status properties?

If not is it best left as is, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it acceptable if I use the same Enum for both status properties?

It is acceptable of course, and I think you should do that. This makes your model more rigorous and obvious and you no longer have to wonder what that number stands for, it makes thinks more explicit and clear.

Also if you switch in the future to using ORM *(Object Relational Mapper)* you will see that they support enumerations and can map them directly to the database.